# regex - capture he or she but do not know which till run

Tags: java, regex

Using a regex expression I would like to be able to make a back reference to a possibility of two words.  By that I mean the text may read,
`.*she|he.*`.
I do not know until running the regex whether the text will read she or he and would like to make a back reference to the word that appeared.

I have tried

```
(she|he)
```

but although this finds the phrase, it does not capture the word.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using? C#, java, PHP, ...?

Comment: What are you trying to do? (she|he) or (s?he) will capture the pronoun, which will be available as \1 in the same expression or as $1 for a callback. All depends on what you're using.

Comment: I am using java.  I want to allow he or she (the pronoun) but also once allowed, I would like to know which was used.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
(\bs?he\b)
```

Given the following input:

```
he 
hesitate 
?she??
shealalala
```

It will match:

```
he 
?she??
```

Comment: +1 @rui jarimba could you explain this as well if I change above regex to`(\bs*he\b)` this one what difference it expresses as i am getting same result using both

Comment: My regex will match **words**, not just **text**. If you try my example input string with this regex `(s?he)` you'll see that it will match text in all lines

Comment: I guess thats what happening with `(\bs*he\b)` as well

Comment: Your regex is wrong, `*` will match **0 or more** characters. You should use `?`, not `*`. Your regex will match the following text: `ssssssshe`

Comment: waaaahhh I fool I am - was missing this silly point, thanks buddy - if it would have been possible would have upvoted to 10 times :)